# dual display with matrox g550 card

Tags: xinerama, matrox

I installed ubuntu 12.04 on my computer and I have a matrox g550, but I have the problem my dual display is clone.

How do I get dual display without being clone?

I tried to make one `xorg.conf` from X -configure and put that file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` and put in this file option `xinerama` `on`, but didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this [tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XineramaHowTo). Did you set `Option "Clone" "off"`?

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the `xorg.conf` directly in Ubuntu.

Just go to `System Settings...`->`Displays` and remove the `Mirror displays` Checkbox. My screenshot is from 12.10 but as I remember the dialog basically looks the same in 12.04.

[image]